# add a layer of hospitals to map in leaflet using R

Tags: r, leaflet, openstreetmap

I made a leaflet map with a polygon of Boston metro, 
is there a way to add an additional layer which shows hospitals and clinics to it ?

I tried searching for layers and the only link I found was

http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

which doesn't have a dedicated layer for hospitals

My code is as follows:

```
leaflet(boston_alldata) %>%
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron', options = tileOptions(minZoom=10, maxZoom=18)) %>%
  setView(-71.0589, 42.3601, zoom = 11) %>%
  addPolygons(data = boston_shp,popup = ~Name,
              stroke = TRUE, weight = 2,
              color = 'gray')%>%
  clearMarkers() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(popup=paste0("Neighborhood:"," ",boston_alldata$neighborhood,","," ",boston_alldata$zip,"<br>",boston_alldata$legend, "<br>", boston_alldata$freq, " observations","<br>","Population Rate: ",boston_alldata$populationrate," per 100,000"),
                   fillOpacity = 0.5,
                   color = ~pal1(boston_alldata$q))%>%
  addLegend("bottomleft",pal = pal1, values = boston_alldata$q,
            title = "Quantiles",opacity = 1)%>%
  addSearchOSM() %>%
  addFullscreenControl%>%
  addMiniMap(tiles = providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap,
             toggleDisplay = T)
```

The leaflet looks as follows

[image: Leaflet Map]

Comment: You can download specific data using Overpass API. The Internet has various Leaflet examples for using Overpass API and displaying the results.